# join multiple queries error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

First query

```
SELECT a.*,
       ifnull(cnt_all,0) total_drivers,
       ifnull(cnt_active,0) active_drivers,
       ifnull(cnt_idle,0) idle_drivers
FROM ta_agent a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT agent_id,
          count(*) cnt_all
   FROM ta_drivers
   GROUP BY agent_id) cnt ON a.agent_id=cnt.agent_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT agent_id,
          count(*) cnt_idle
   FROM ta_drivers
   WHERE last_viewed=0
   GROUP BY agent_id) idle ON a.agent_id=idle.agent_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT agent_id,
          count(*) cnt_active
   FROM ta_drivers
   WHERE last_viewed=1
   GROUP BY agent_id) active ON a.agent_id=active.agent_id
```

Second query

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS user_registeredon
FROM ta_agent a,
     ta_subscription s
WHERE s.agent_id = a.agent_id
```

These two queries working fine when I run separately. I want to join these two queries. I have tried to join these two queries but I got this error `Every derived table must have its own alias`

I have tried this

```
select a.*, ifnull(cnt_all,0) total_drivers,ifnull(cnt_active,0) active_drivers, ifnull(cnt_idle,0) idle_drivers
    from ta_agent a left join (select agent_id, count(*) cnt_all
                       from ta_drivers
                       group by agent_id) cnt on a.agent_id=cnt.agent_id

    left join (select agent_id, count(*) cnt_idle
                       from ta_drivers
                       where last_viewed=0
                       group by agent_id) idle on a.agent_id=idle.agent_id

    left join (select agent_id, count(*) cnt_active
                       from ta_drivers
                       where last_viewed=1
                       group by agent_id) active on a.agent_id=active.agent_id

    left join(SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( date_of_registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS user_registeredon FROM ta_subscription WHERE agent_id = a.agent_id)
```

I don't think this is the correct method to get the result..

Comment: How are you joining them?

Comment: I have just used left join to join those two queries. I'm not sure whether it is a correct method or not

Comment: It depends on how you write it. Since the error is saying you are missing an alias, and both base queries work on their own... then the problem must be in how you are writing that left join.

Comment: show us how you tried to join those 2 query?

Comment: That said... the first query looks quite ugly. I'd use subselects and take out all those left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mentioned how do you want to join this two query..
Looking for something like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.*,
          ifnull(cnt_all,0) total_drivers,
          ifnull(cnt_active,0) active_drivers,
          ifnull(cnt_idle,0) idle_drivers
   FROM ta_agent a
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT agent_id,
             count(*) cnt_all
      FROM ta_drivers
      GROUP BY agent_id) cnt ON a.agent_id=cnt.agent_id
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT agent_id,
             count(*) cnt_idle
      FROM ta_drivers
      WHERE last_viewed=0
      GROUP BY agent_id) idle ON a.agent_id=idle.agent_id
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT agent_id,
             count(*) cnt_active
      FROM ta_drivers
      WHERE last_viewed=1
      GROUP BY agent_id) active ON a.agent_id=active.agent_id)tempaliasA
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS user_registeredon,
          agent_id
   FROM ta_agent a,
        ta_subscription s
   WHERE s.agent_id = a.agent_id)tempaliasB ON tempaliasA.agent_id = tempaliasB.agent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do it without all those joins, then this should do it:

```
SELECT a.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM ta_drivers
    WHERE agent_id=a.agent_id
  ) AS total_drivers,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM ta_drivers
    WHERE agent_id=a.agent_id AND lastviewed=1
  ) AS active_drivers,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM ta_drivers
    WHERE agent_id=a.agent_id AND lastviewed=0
  ) AS idle_drivers,
  (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_registration, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
    FROM ta_subscription
    WHERE agent_id=a.agent_i
  ) AS user_registered
```

I'd add that maybe the problem with what you were trying to do is that in both single queries you are using an alias "a"... when you combine them then the resulting query is ambiguous.